# bash's arcana with loop

Tags: bash, loops

Have some function with loop:

```
runcfg () {

o=0

while (( o<3 )); do
  echo $o
  (( o++ ))
done

}
```

It calls from another script `manager.sh` by:

```
...
    -C|--runconfig)
source $APP_BASEDIR/app-install/bin/config_functions; runcfg;
shift;;
...
```

Let's run it:

```
$ bash -x manager.sh -run
```

And look at output:

```
...
+ runcfg
+ o=0
+ ((  o<3  ))
+ echo 0
0
+ ((  o++  ))
```

That's all lines... Nothing else happens.

But! If make little chage and add `&&` after arithmetic call:

```
runcfg () {

o=0

while (( o<3 )); do
  echo $o
  (( o++ )) && echo ++OK || echo ++ER
done

}
```

It works!

```
...
+ runcfg
+ o=0
+ ((  o<3  ))
+ echo 0
0
+ ((  o++  ))
+ echo ++ER
++ER
+ ((  o<3  ))
+ echo 1
1
+ ((  o++  ))
+ echo ++OK
++OK
+ ((  o<3  ))
+ echo 2
2
+ ((  o++  ))
+ echo ++OK
++OK
+ ((  o<3  ))
+ shift
...
```

What is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is configured to exit on error (note that it prints `++ER` the first time), and `((o++))` == `((0))`, which returns 1 (an error). Options:

- Use `let o++` instead.
- Ignore the error (`((o++))||:`)
- Use a for loop (`for ((o = 0; o < 3; o++))`)
- Turn off exit-on-error (`set +e`).